# How do I override the first argument of a parent service in yaml?

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

From monolog.xml:

```
    <service id="monolog.logger" parent="monolog.logger_prototype" public="false">
        <argument index="0">app</argument>
    </service>

    <service id="logger" alias="monolog.logger" />

    <service id="monolog.logger_prototype" class="%monolog.logger.class%" abstract="true">
        <argument /><!-- Channel -->
    </service>
```

How do I accomplish the same overriding of the 0th argument in Yaml?

Comment: Basically you're asking *"How to convert this piece of xml configuration into yml"*? Or did you try to convert it on your own and faced a problem?

Comment: I tried to do the same thing in yml, but couldn't figure out what the notation should be and I don't think I can easily just convert it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My colleague created [a bundle that allows you to easily convert from XML to YML](https://github.com/rosstuck/TuckConverterBundle) and it came up with:

```
services:
    monolog.logger:
        public: false
        arguments: { index_0: app }

    monolog.logger_prototype:
        class: %monolog.logger.class%
        arguments: ['']

    logger: @monolog.logger
```

Never would have guessed that.

Answer (score 0):

One of defining logger with custom channel as service way:

```
# app/config/config.yml
monolog:
    channels: [custom_channel]
```

When in a controller:
`$logger = $this->get('monolog.logger.custom_channel')`;

or when defining a service:

```
services:
    app.logger.custom_channel:
        parent: monolog.logger.custom_channel
```